I18n localization failing when upgrading to Angular 17
The error message is - zone.js:1049 Error: NG0204: Can't resolve all parameters for I18n: (?, ?, ?).
It works when using Angular 15 and I have tried switching to using @ngx-translate/core but I don't want to waste too much rewriting all my html and typescript code.
app.module.ts
import { I18n } from "@ngx-translate/i18n-polyfill";

@NgModule({
    imports: [
    ],
    declarations: [AppComponent],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent],
    providers: [
        {
            provide: TRANSLATIONS, useFactory: (locale) => {
                switch (locale) {
                    case 'ja':
                        locale = 'ja';
                        break;
                    case 'ru':
                        locale = 'ru';
                        break;
                    default:
                        locale = 'en-US';
                }
                return require(`raw-loader!../locale/messages.${locale}.xlf`).default;
            },
            deps: [LOCALE_ID]
        },
        {
            provide: LOCALE_ID,
            useFactory: localeFactory
        },
        [I18n],
    ]
})

